# How to check how many files contain errors (while building) in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, build, compiler-errors, compilation, visual-studio-2019

I want to have the number of files which contain building errors in my Visual Studio Solution. Is there a way to do that in Visual Studio 2019? I know about Error list window, showing the number of errors and files where those errors occurred, but I need the number of files which contain those errors, it can be approximate number.

Comment: That will be very tricky if one (or more) of your build errors involves a missing symbol definition! What file would it be missing from? ;-)

Comment: Definitely, also approximate number of files would be fine :)